# Subqueries in SQL from airline management scheme

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Here `f` refer to `air_flight` and `fp` refer to `air_flight_details`.
As I'm beginner for sql I understand the concept except.... why they are mentioning `fp` after subquery and whyy not as `air_flight_details fp`?

```
SELECT f.flight_id, f.from_location, f.to_location, fp.Month_Name, fp.Average_Price  
FROM air_flight f,
    (
        SELECT flight_id,  MONTHNAME(flight_departure_date) AS Month_Name,  
            AVG(price) as Average_Price
        FROM air_flight_details
        GROUP BY flight_id, MONTHNAME(flight_departure_date)
    ) fp
WHERE f.flight_id = fp.flight_id AND f.airline_name = 'ABC AIRLINES'
ORDER BY f.flight_id, fp.Month_Name
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please un-tag product not involved.

Comment: @jarlh The concept of a table alias won't be that different between the various flavors of SQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, perhaps not. But since the query isn't ANSI SQL compliant, I think it's a good idea to tag product used. Why tag products not involved?

Comment: My guess is that she just pulled the query from a website somewhere without knowing which RDBMS was being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery in your example has an *alias* called `fp`, which allows the results from that subquery to be referenced in the outer query.  For example, the query selects `fp.Average_Price`, which is a column contained in the subquery.  Also, the `WHERE` clause contains the condition `f.flight_id = fp.flight_id`, which also uses the alias `fp`.

To be clear, `fp` and `air_flight_details` are two distinct tables.

Comment: so u means that fp table refer air_flight_details table and get the required data ?

Comment: No.  `fp` refers to a temporary inner table generated from the inner query in your example.  After the query completes, the "`fp`" table will not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the first `FROM` statement names the table `f`, the entire subquery is given the alias `fp`.

The difference is that in the first `FROM` statement, the entire table `air_flight` is given the name `f`, while the subquery essentially creates an entire table to which `fp` refers.

Comment: while the subquery essentially creates an entire table to which fp refers.Can u briefly explain ths pls

Comment: Just as the `air_flight` table is given the name `f`, the subquery is given the name `fp`, and can be used just like a regular table.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html):

```
(
    SELECT flight_id,  MONTHNAME(flight_departure_date) AS Month_Name,  
        AVG(price) as Average_Price
    FROM air_flight_details
    GROUP BY flight_id, MONTHNAME(flight_departure_date)
) fp
```

Derived tables behave like "ordinary" tables, except that they are constructed from subqueries. In most SQL dialects, including MySQL, derived tables need to be aliased, which is why there is `fp` written after the derived table.

A derived table is nothing else than a "local view". The same query could have been written with a "stored view":

```
CREATE VIEW air_flight_details_with_average_prices AS         
    SELECT flight_id,  MONTHNAME(flight_departure_date) AS Month_Name,  
        AVG(price) as Average_Price
    FROM air_flight_details
    GROUP BY flight_id, MONTHNAME(flight_departure_date);
```

And then:

```
SELECT f.flight_id, f.from_location, f.to_location, fp.Month_Name, fp.Average_Price  
FROM air_flight f, air_flight_details_with_average_prices fp
WHERE f.flight_id = fp.flight_id AND f.airline_name = 'ABC AIRLINES'
ORDER BY f.flight_id, fp.Month_Name
```